# Hide actionbar on touch android

Tags: android, touch, hide, android-actionbar

I want to hide the top actionbar that I have as an overlay on touch and then show it again on another touch. Somehow I should probably add an onTouchListener to something but how? The event should only be handled when its not consumed by other handlers so that my multitouch will still work when I slide to change image etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work (not tested code - so take with grain of salt)

Basically, override onTouch, and call its super method as to not lose functionality. Check if its consumed, else toggle or whatever to show/hide action bar.

```
Boolean showBar = true; // Global variable

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   Boolean result = super.onTouch(v,event);

   if(!result) // False - Not consumed event.
   {
       if(showBar) // Toggle action bar visiblity
          getActionBar().hide();
       else
          getActionBar().show();

       showBar = !showBar;
   }
   return result;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work. The boolean result is always true for some reason. I have not found out why yet.

Comment: It must always be consumed then. In the `onTouch` use `event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK` to get the event, then depending on what event you wish to trigger on, apply the hide/show there